# Python open() a url file

Tags: python

I'm quite new with Python, and I'm trying to find out how to read a remote file without having to download it.
Normally, if the file is on my HDD, I just have to do

```
with open('file.jpg', "rb") as file:
   data = file.read()
```

And then I have a stream of my file.

Now, if the file is located at a http://.../file.jpg I obviously can't use open().
I don't want to download it then open it from hard drive but directly stream it from its original URL. How can I do that?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use the `requests` module to read from URLs.

Comment: I would like to add that it would be courteous to save the file to the user's disk too once you've got it for the first time, to save their bandwidth and the host's

Comment: Although you could use a third party library like `requests`, Python's own `urllib.request.urlopen` works in most simple cases and functions just like `open()` for files, which is convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get(url).content))
```